# GIMP - Adding new layer blocks image below

Tags: gimp, layers

I have a JPG image, then I add a new layer on top, with Mode: Color, and fill with color red.  I get what I want, where the image below shows through:

[image]

But when I do the **exact same thing** on another image (also JPG), that image is completely blocked:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  In both cases, the Layer Fill Type of the new layer is set to Transparency.  In both cases, I use the same red color to fill the layer.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, the second image that was being blocked was grayscale.  I changed it to RGB using:

Image -> Mode -> RGB

Afterwards, it was OK.  Hope this helps others.